# TestNG XSLT (Saxon) Report Generator Jars

Tags: selenium, xslt, jar, testng, saxon

I am trying to generate XSLT file using TestNG + Selenium + Java.

I find out that to do so , we need to have these three jar files

- saxon-8.7.jar
- SaxonLiaison.jar
- testng-xslt-maven-plugin-test-0.0.jar

I got those files from separated sources and mostly from someone's personal repository.

- Is there any *official webpage* to download the latest version of those three jar files?

I went to [Saxon Page](http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) and apparently we need to pay to use Saxon product? Not sure if I am on the right page though.

- Are those 3 Jar files mentioned above free of charge? Thanks.

Comment: What is testng-xslt-maven-plugin-test-0.0.jar? Where do you find it?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer part of the question.

I don't know if testNG/Selenium really requires Saxon 8.7 specifically (that's a very old version) or whether it will also run with more recent versions. Sometimes when people say the requirement is for version X, they simply mean that's the one that it was tested with. Either way, I think it almost certainly requires only the open source version of Saxon (which was called Saxon-B up to version 9.1, and Saxon-HE from versions 9.2 to the current 9.7). For all the open-source versions, the official distribution is on the Saxon project at Sourceforge, https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/ Obviously, for these versions no license (or payment) is required.

The page you cite from www.saxonica.com is only relevant to commercial versions of Saxon. I guess we should correct it, because we should allow for users landing there from a google search and therefore not assume any context.

I can't help you on the other two JAR files.